# How to enable modelica unit consistency check

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to enable warnings about unit mismatches (dimentionality) on modelica code.
Here is the test code I mis-formulated on purpose:

```
class test
Real v(final unit="V");
Real i(final unit="A");
parameter Real r(start = 120, final unit="Ohm");
equation
    v = i * i * r;
    v = sin(time);
end test;
```

Here is the script I used for compiling:

```
loadModel(Modelica); 
loadFile("test.mo");
simulate(test, stopTime=10);
plot(i);
```

I compile the code above with the following command:

```
omc t.mos --debug=dumpEqInUC --debug=dumpEqUCStruct --debug=dumpUnits
```

But there is no warning about units. How to enable unit check?
Thanks.

omc version: 1.9.3+dev (r25940)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to script,

```
setCommandLineOptions("--preOptModules+=unitChecking");
```

Comment: It works with v1.9.4-dev.beta2.79+g3f4477c, says UnitCheck COMPLETED if it is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to enable this in OMEdit?

Comment: Add "--preOptModules+=unitChecking" to Tools->Options->Simulation->Additional Translation Flags: